# Using React.createRef in class component has current as always null

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple parent and child class component:

```
class Parent extends.React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context)
        this.childRef = React.createRef()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.childRef)
    }

    render() {
        return <ChildComponent ref={this.childRef} />
    }
}
```

The `console.log` statement in the `componentDidMount` function prints out: `{ current: null }`

Why is this?

My `react` and `react-dom` packages are both at 16.14.

Comment: Can you add code example of the ChildComponent? Might help identifying issue.

Answer (score 1):

In `ChildComponent` you need to forward ref. Example:

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.props.innerRef}>
        Div has a ref
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChildComponent innerRef={ref} {...props}/>);
```